# Use geom_label_repel only for certain observations?

Tags: ggplot2, ggrepel, ggimage

I'm a football data analyst using NFL team logos as my points on a scatterplot.  However, these images will sometimes cover each other up.  I want to find a way to repel a label for those images that are overlapping with one another.  However, I only want to have a repelled label for points where the team image is not fully visible.  Is there a way to have R only insert labels for a few datapoints?  I've attached an image below in which all datapoints have a label attached.  My current call to geom_label_repel is:

`ggplot + geom_label_repel(label.size = 0.1)`

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

[image: Current ggplot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to choose the labels you want:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

df <- tribble(~team, ~aay, ~epa,
        "LA", 8, 5,
        "PIT", 6, -2,
        "KC", 7, 5,
        "DAL", 7, 5
        )

# Select desired labels
labels <- df |> filter(team %in% c("KC", "DAL"))

df |> 
  ggplot(aes(aay, epa)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = team), data = labels, force = 20) +
  xlim(c(0, 10)) +
  ylim(c(-8, 8))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>